# Why is the Hazelcast Near Cache out of sync with the EntryUpdatedListener even though they're in the same process?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I understand that Near Caches are not guaranteed to be synchronized real-time when the value is updated elsewhere on some other node.

However I do expect it to be in sync with the EntryUpdatedListener that is on the same node and therefore the same process - or am I missing something?

Sequence of events:

Cluster of 1 node modifies the same key/value, flipping a value from X to Y and back to X on an interval every X seconds.

A client connects to this cluster node and adds an EntryUpdatedListener to observe the flipping value.

Client receives the EntryUpdatedEvent and prints the value given - as expected, it gives the value recently set.

Client immediately does a map.get for the same key (which should hit the near cache), and it prints a STALE value.

I find this strange - it means that two "channels" within the same client process are showing inconsistent versions of data. I would only expect this between different processes.

Below is my reproducer code:

```
public class ClusterTest {
    private static final int OLD_VALUE = 10000;
    private static final int NEW_VALUE = 88888;
    private static final int KEY = 5;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

        IMap map = instance.getMap("test");
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES; i++) {
            map.put(i, 0);
        }

        System.out.println("Size of map = " + map.size());

        boolean flag = false;

        while(true) {
            int value = flag ? OLD_VALUE : NEW_VALUE;
            flag = !flag;

            map.put(KEY, value);

            System.out.println("Set a value of [" + value + "]: ");

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

public class ClientTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        HazelcastInstance instance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(new ClientConfig().addNearCacheConfig(new NearCacheConfig("test")));
        IMap map = instance.getMap("test");
        System.out.println("Size of map = " + map.size());

        map.addEntryListener(new MyEntryListener(instance), true);

        new CountDownLatch(1).await();
    }

    static class MyEntryListener
            implements EntryAddedListener,
            EntryUpdatedListener,
            EntryRemovedListener {
        private HazelcastInstance instance;

        public MyEntryListener(HazelcastInstance instance) {
            this.instance = instance;
        }

        @Override
        public void entryAdded(EntryEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Entry Added:" + event);
        }

        @Override
        public void entryRemoved(EntryEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Entry Removed:" + event);
        }

        @Override
        public void entryUpdated(EntryEvent event) {
            Object o = instance.getMap("test").get(event.getKey());
            boolean equals = o.equals(event.getValue());
            String s = "Event matches what has been fetched = " + equals;

            if (!equals) {
                s += ", EntryEvent value has delivered: " + (event.getValue()) + ", and an explicit GET has delivered:" + o;
            }

            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

The output from the client:

```
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.11.1] HazelcastClient 3.11.1 (20181218 - d294f31) is CLIENT_CONNECTED
Jun 20, 2019 4:58:15 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics
INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.11.1] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
Size of map = 10
Event matches what has been fetched = true
Event matches what has been fetched = false, EntryEvent value has delivered: 88888, and an explicit GET has delivered:10000
Event matches what has been fetched = true
Event matches what has been fetched = true
Event matches what has been fetched = false, EntryEvent value has delivered: 10000, and an explicit GET has delivered:88888
```

Answer (score 0):

Near Cache has Eventual Consistency guarantee, while Listeners work in a fire & forget fashion. That's why there are two different mechanisms for both. Also, batching for near cache events reduces the network traffic and keeps the eventing system less busy (this helps when there are too many invalidations or clients), as a tradeoff it may increase the delay of individual invalidations. If you are confident that your system can handle each invalidation event, you can disable batching.

You need to configure the property on member side as events are generated on cluster members and sent to clients.